# Wanted to Verify about this clamscan SUMMARY

Tags: security, clamav

What does the scan summary entails or describes line by line?

[image: Screenshot of the scan!]

```
SCAN SUMMARY ----

Known Viruses: 5476860

----
```

I was shocked it found 5 million viruses
Can somebody please explain this to me sorry I am pretty new to clamAV.

What necessary steps do I need to do to secure my linux machine?

I need some tips or guides on how to secure my machine step by step.

Comment: This is the number of the viruses, which clamAV can recognise. You have `Infected files: 0`.

Comment: oh wow I thought this are all viruses inside my machine.I just started scanning now after doing some programming lol and install alot of packages

Answer (score 5):

The 'known viruses' field is likely how many viruses ClamAV knows exists. The relevant fields seem to be conventionally:

```
 Scanned files: 35
 Infected files: 0
```

So it scanned `35` files, and found `0` containing the `5476860` known viruses 
- please note that this does mean those files could theoretically contain any unknown viruses.

Comment: Thank you , but it doesnt mean linux really secure right? I was in panic mode after I saw 5 million known viruses

Comment: Yes it does mean Linux is secure. By default it is built as a multi-user system and to keep files secure from your OWN users (so not even outside influences) you need a working security model. The main issue regarding securing Linux is the user.  Pick a stupid password and you can get burned. Leave your system open with a sudo session active and you can get burned.